# Flutter / Google Map not showing on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I implemented Google Maps in my flutter application using
this package: https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter. It's shown in an Android emulator but it's not shown on an iOS Simulator and an actual iOS device(my iPhone).

[image]

#### Environment

- It was working fine when using **Flutter 1.22.6** and **CocoaPods 1.9.3**, but after updating to **Flutter 2.2.3** and **CocoaPods 1.10.1**, it started to not appear.
- I also enabled both `Maps SDK for Android` and `Maps SDK for iOS` in Google Cloud Platform for this project.
- Setting `io.flutter.embedded_views_preview` to `true` in Info.plist

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you using the same API key for Android and iOS? If yes, is it unrestricted or not?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the API keys first, you may have to use a separate one for iOS.